# Can someone tell me what <g> and </g> in an svg?

Tags: svg

I have this svg.  Can someone tell me what all the  and  are there for and can the be removed?

```html
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
    <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
      viewBox="0 0 490.034 490.034" style="enable-background:new 0 0 490.034 490.034;" xml:space="preserve">
    <g>
     <g>
      <path d="M435.667,54.311c-7-7.1-18.4-7-25.5,0l-64,64c-79.3-36-163.9-27.2-244.6,25.5c-60.1,39.2-96.6,88.5-98.1,90.6
       c-4.8,6.6-4.6,15.6,0.5,22c34.2,42,70,74.7,106.6,97.5l-56.3,56.3c-7,7-7,18.4,0,25.5c3.5,3.5,8.1,5.3,12.7,5.3s9.2-1.8,12.7-5.3
       l356-355.9C442.667,72.811,442.667,61.411,435.667,54.311z M200.467,264.011c-2.6-5.9-3.9-12.3-3.9-19c0-12.9,5-25.1,14.2-34.3
       c14.4-14.4,35.7-17.8,53.3-10.3L200.467,264.011z M290.667,173.911c-32.7-21-76.8-17.2-105.3,11.3c-16,16-24.7,37.2-24.7,59.7
       c0,16.4,4.7,32.1,13.4,45.6l-37.1,37.1c-32.5-18.8-64.5-46.6-95.6-82.9c13.3-15.6,41.4-45.7,79.9-70.8
       c66.6-43.4,132.9-52.8,197.5-28.1L290.667,173.911z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
    <g>
     <g>
      <path d="M486.067,233.611c-24.7-30.4-50.3-56-76.3-76.3c-7.9-6.1-19.2-4.7-25.4,3.1c-6.1,7.8-4.7,19.1,3.1,25.3
       c20.6,16.1,41.2,36.1,61.2,59.5c-11.8,13.8-34.8,38.6-66,61.3c-60.1,43.7-120.8,59.5-180.3,46.9c-9.7-2.1-19.3,4.2-21.3,13.9
       c-2.1,9.7,4.2,19.3,13.9,21.3c15.5,3.3,31.1,4.9,46.8,4.9c23.6,0,47.4-3.7,71.1-11.1c31.1-9.7,62-25.7,91.9-47.5
       c50.4-36.9,80.5-77.6,81.8-79.3C491.367,249.011,491.167,240.011,486.067,233.611z"/>
     </g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    <g>
    </g>
    </svg>
```

Comment: [The g element documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/g) should answer that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Andrew Morton has hinted in the comments, the [g element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/g) is a container element, to group together other elements and apply the same attributes to all child elements.

In your code snippet, it looks like the SVG was generated/exported using Adobe Illustrator, which might explain all the empty `<g>` elements, which can safely be removed. In fact, all the `<g>` elements in your code seem redundant, and the same output is produced without them:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 490.034 490.034" style="enable-background:new 0 0 490.034 490.034;" xml:space="preserve">
    <path d="M435.667,54.311c-7-7.1-18.4-7-25.5,0l-64,64c-79.3-36-163.9-27.2-244.6,25.5c-60.1,39.2-96.6,88.5-98.1,90.6
        c-4.8,6.6-4.6,15.6,0.5,22c34.2,42,70,74.7,106.6,97.5l-56.3,56.3c-7,7-7,18.4,0,25.5c3.5,3.5,8.1,5.3,12.7,5.3s9.2-1.8,12.7-5.3
        l356-355.9C442.667,72.811,442.667,61.411,435.667,54.311z M200.467,264.011c-2.6-5.9-3.9-12.3-3.9-19c0-12.9,5-25.1,14.2-34.3
        c14.4-14.4,35.7-17.8,53.3-10.3L200.467,264.011z M290.667,173.911c-32.7-21-76.8-17.2-105.3,11.3c-16,16-24.7,37.2-24.7,59.7
        c0,16.4,4.7,32.1,13.4,45.6l-37.1,37.1c-32.5-18.8-64.5-46.6-95.6-82.9c13.3-15.6,41.4-45.7,79.9-70.8
        c66.6-43.4,132.9-52.8,197.5-28.1L290.667,173.911z"/>
    <path d="M486.067,233.611c-24.7-30.4-50.3-56-76.3-76.3c-7.9-6.1-19.2-4.7-25.4,3.1c-6.1,7.8-4.7,19.1,3.1,25.3
        c20.6,16.1,41.2,36.1,61.2,59.5c-11.8,13.8-34.8,38.6-66,61.3c-60.1,43.7-120.8,59.5-180.3,46.9c-9.7-2.1-19.3,4.2-21.3,13.9
        c-2.1,9.7,4.2,19.3,13.9,21.3c15.5,3.3,31.1,4.9,46.8,4.9c23.6,0,47.4-3.7,71.1-11.1c31.1-9.7,62-25.7,91.9-47.5
        c50.4-36.9,80.5-77.6,81.8-79.3C491.367,249.011,491.167,240.011,486.067,233.611z"/>
</svg>
```